how do get rid of invalid command name "2454343926912update"
invalid command name "2454343926912update"
    while executing
"2454343926912update"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "2454379091328check_dpi_scaling"
    while executing
"2454379091328check_dpi_scaling"
    ("after" script)

cmd showing this error, I read on one of the posts that it is the problem with .destroy() but what ever I tried from the comments it didnt help either when program closed it would keep running because .withdraw is just putting it behind or something else...
here is my code:
# Importing required modules
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from main_window import create_main_window
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import json


def create_login_window():

    customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
    customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

    app = customtkinter.CTk()
    app.geometry("800x600")
    app.title('Login')

    # Get screen dimensions
    screen_width = app.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = app.winfo_screenheight()

    # Calculate window width and height
    window_width = int(screen_width * 0.8)
    window_height = int(screen_height * 0.8)

    # Calculate window position to center it on the screen
    x_position = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
    y_position = (screen_height - window_height) // 2

    # Set window size and position
    app.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x_position}+{y_position}")

    def login(event=None):

        _ = event  # Use '_' to indicate that the 'event' parameter is not used explicitly

        entered_username = entry1.get()
        entered_password = entry2.get()

        # Admin login
        if entered_username == "ADMIN" and entered_password == "ADMIN":
            # Destroy current window and create the main window
            app.destroy()
            create_main_window()
            return

        else:
            # Load user data from JSON file
            try:
                with open("user_data.json", "r") as json_file:
                    user_data = json.load(json_file)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "User data file not found.")
                return

            # Check if entered username and password match any user in the JSON data
            for user in user_data:
                if user["username"] == entered_username and user["password"] == entered_password:
                    # If match found, destroy current window and create the main window
                    app.destroy()
                    create_main_window()
                    return

            # If no match found, show error message
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid username or password. Please try again.")

    frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app, width=500, height=400, corner_radius=30)
    frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    l1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="Log into your account", font=('Century Gothic', 40))
    l1.place(x=45, y=45)

    entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, width=400, height=40, placeholder_text='Username')
    entry1.place(x=45, y=130)

    entry2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, width=400, height=40, placeholder_text='Password', show="*")
    entry2.place(x=45, y=215)

    button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, width=200, height=50, text="Login", command=login, corner_radius=6)
    button1.place(x=150, y=300)

    app.bind('<Return>', login)

    # Set focus to the username entry widget after a short delay
    app.after(100, entry1.focus)

    app.mainloop()

.withdraw() doesnt work or I used it wrong.
.exit() as well

Does the app otherwise work correctly?  Developers accustomed to Windows often spew debug messages to the console because they won't be seen, whereas they are on Linux.

Yes otherwise everything works, but i am like that I want everything sorted out


i think this can be for :  you run function create_main_window  after the app.destroy and when app close it cant run code for you you can run your functions and codes and then destroy the app



# Importing required modules
import tkinter
import customtkinter
from main_window import create_main_window
import tkinter.messagebox as messagebox
import json


def create_login_window():
    def login(event=None):

        _ = event  # Use '_' to indicate that the 'event' parameter is not used explicitly

        entered_username = entry1.get()
        entered_password = entry2.get()

        # Admin login
        if entered_username == "ADMIN" and entered_password == "ADMIN":
            # Destroy current window and create the main window
            create_main_window()
            app.destroy()

        else:
            # Load user data from JSON file
            try:
                with open("user_data.json", "r") as json_file:
                    user_data = json.load(json_file)
            except FileNotFoundError:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "User data file not found.")


            # Check if entered username and password match any user in the JSON data
            for user in user_data:
                if user["username"] == entered_username and user["password"] == entered_password:
                    # If match found, destroy current window and create the main window
                    create_main_window()
                    app.destroy()
                    

            # If no match found, show error message
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Invalid username or password. Please try again.")

    customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
    customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")

    app = customtkinter.CTk()
    app.geometry("800x600")
    app.title('Login')

    # Get screen dimensions
    screen_width = app.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = app.winfo_screenheight()

    # Calculate window width and height
    window_width = int(screen_width * 0.8)
    window_height = int(screen_height * 0.8)

    # Calculate window position to center it on the screen
    x_position = (screen_width - window_width) // 2
    y_position = (screen_height - window_height) // 2

    # Set window size and position
    app.geometry(f"{window_width}x{window_height}+{x_position}+{y_position}")

    frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=app, width=500, height=400, corner_radius=30)
    frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)

    l1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(master=frame, text="Log into your account", font=('Century Gothic', 40))
    l1.place(x=45, y=45)

    entry1 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, width=400, height=40, placeholder_text='Username')
    entry1.place(x=45, y=130)

    entry2 = customtkinter.CTkEntry(master=frame, width=400, height=40, placeholder_text='Password', show="*")
    entry2.place(x=45, y=215)

    button1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=frame, width=200, height=50, text="Login", command=login, corner_radius=6)
    button1.place(x=150, y=300)

    app.bind('<Return>', login)

    # Set focus to the username entry widget after a short delay
    app.after(100, entry1.focus)

    app.mainloop()



Thank you very much I will try it on monday and will get back to you with the results
